# Swift - Multiply two NSDecimal Numbers

Tags: swift, multiplication, nsdecimalnumber

I am currently attempting to multiply two `NSDecimal` Numbers, is this possible in **Swift**?

I found the method '`decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy`' on the Apple Dev pages but I have used it as below and I am receiving a '**Bad access**' error.

Purchase Price and Quantity are both `NSDecimalNumbers` in the Item class and are definitely populated (with purchase price of 35.99 and quantity of 30)

```
var one = item.purchasePrice
var two = item.quantity

let three: NSDecimalNumber = one.decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy(two)
```

I have tried it multiple ways but all the tutorials seem to be for Objective C.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

that works perfectly.

```
var numberOne: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(float: 35.99)
var numberTwo: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(int: 30)
let numberThree: NSDecimalNumber = numberOne.decimalNumberByMultiplyingBy(numberTwo)

print(numberThree)
```

the output on the console is:

```
1079.7000503540041728
```

---

*NOTE: your var's type (`three`) may **not** be `NSDecimalNumber` instances, that is why you got the exception.*

Comment: Thanks for letting me know I wasn't going crazy! Turns out my exception was occurring because I had changed the variable type of 'item.quantity. but hadn't update the Core Data - DUH. Thanks for reminding me to check that all the types were correct @holex

Answer (score 1):

I do not trust the integrity of the NSDecimalNumber class. Just look at the following code:

type the following in the playground:

`var number1: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(float: 35.99)`

you get: **35.99000167846681**

`var number2: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: "35.99")`

you get: **35.98999999999999**

`var number3: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(int: 3599)`

you get: **3599**

`var number4: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(int: 100)`

you get: **100**

`let number5: NSDecimalNumber = number3.decimalNumberByDividingBy(number4)`

you get: **35.98999999999999**

Take a close look at `number2` and `number5` they should have exact representation if this was a true Decimal class.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I just checked in Playground. `print(number1)` gives me no problems at all. Maybe you are converting to double before printing?

Answer (score 0):

for Swift 5

```
var amount:Double = 1.66

var nsValue: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: String(amount))

var nsValue1: NSDecimalNumber = NSDecimalNumber(string: "1.22")


var nsValue3: NSDecimalNumber = nsValue.multiplying(by: nsValue1)

print(nsValue3)
```

output

```
2.0252
```

I know this is way too late to answer but someone might find it helpful.